# Computing rolling sums of stretches a vector with R

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I have a long vector x, and another v, which contains lengths.  I would like to sum x so that the answer `y` is a vector of length `length(v)`, and `y[1]` is `sum(x[1:v[i]])`, `y[2]` is `sum(x[(1+v[1]):(v[1]+v[2])])`, and so on.  Essentially this is performing sparse matrix multiplication from a space of dimension `length(x)` to one of dimension `length(v)`.  However, I would prefer not to bring in "advanced machinery", although I might have to. It does need to be very, very fast.  Can anyone think of anything simpler than using a sparse matrix package?

Example -

```
x <- c(1,1,3,4,5)
v <- c(2,3)
y <- myFunc(x,v)
```

`y` should be `c(2,12)`

I am open to any pre-processing - e.g, storing in v the starting indexes of each stretch.

Comment: Should `1:v[i]` be `1:v[1]` in the second sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  y <- cumsum(x)[cumsum(v)]
  y <- c(y[1], diff(y))
```

This looks like it's doing extra work because it's computing the cumsum for the whole vector, but it's actually faster than the other solutions so far, for both small and large numbers of groups.

Here's how I simulated the data

```
set.seed(5)
N <- 1e6
n <- 10
x <- round(runif(N,0,100),1)
v <- as.vector(table(sample(n, N, replace=TRUE)))
```

On my machine the timings with `n <- 10` are:

- Brandon Bertelsen (for loop): 0.017
- Ramnath (rowsum): 0.057
- John (split/apply): 0.280
- Aaron (cumsum): 0.008

changing to `n <- 1e5` the timings are:

- Brandon Bertelsen (for loop): 2.181
- Ramnath (rowsum): 0.226
- John (split/apply): 0.852
- Aaron (cumsum): 0.015

I suspect this is faster than doing matrix multiplication, even with a sparse matrix package, because one doesn't have to form the matrix or do any multiplication.  If more speed is needed, I suspect it could be sped up by writing it in C; not hard to do with the `inline` and `rcpp` packages, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: +1 I believe this is the right way to do it.  It will have almost the fastest possible throughput because the memory can be pre-allocated and it is completely vectorized.  One can potentially improve the calculations by doing `cumsum(x)` and `cumsum(v)` in parallel, using the `parallel()` command from the `multicore` package.

Comment: I'd be interested in understanding why the for loop seems to get slower as n increases.

Comment: n is the length of v, so as n increases, the for loop has more to loop over.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `rowsum`. It should be reasonably fast as it uses `C` code in the background.

```
y <- rowsum(x, rep(1:length(v), v))
```

Comment: how did you generate your dummy data? note that `v` cant be any arbitrary vector. `sum(v)` should equal `length(x)`

Comment: just x <- 1:100000 , v <- 1:100000

Comment: that does not work since `sum(v)` is not equal to `length(x)`. note that the last element accessed by the user is `x[sum(v)]` and for that to exist `sum(v) <= length(x)`

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I think the for loop is still a bit faster... strange, I expected the vectorized function to be faster.

Comment: can you put your data as example so that i can see why the loop works faster?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: depends how many groups there are; the for loop is faster when the number of groups is small, I suspect because the sum within it is really fast.  But when the number of the groups is large, it becomes slow, and can be slower even than the split solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different tack.

```
s <- rep(1:length(v), v)
l <- split(x, s)
y <- sapply(l, sum)
```

Comment: Or equivalently in one line using `tapply`: `tapply(x,rep(1:length(v),v),sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(v)) { 
    y[i] <- ifelse(i > 1,sum(x[v[i-1]:v[i]]), sum(x[1:v[i]]))
}
```

Comment: I think this needs a `v <- cumsum(v)` and also, the `v[i-1]` should be `(v[i-1]+1)`

Comment: Better yet, `v <- c(0, cumsum(v))` to remove the `ifelse`.